# Geometry Nodes: "Attribute Randomize" - What are the Attribute Variables?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am attempting to use geometry nodes to scatter stuff and I have a handle on the basics of the **Point Distribute** - **Point Scale** - **Point Instance** chain that allows for basic scattering.

However, I am attempting to Add an **Attribute Randomize** to ensure that my scattered objects aren't all pointing in the same direction. However, while every tutorial I have watched puts "scale" in that Attribute field, I would love to know what *else* can be placed there.

I know that this is in-process, but I'm sure there has to be a running log of variables. I've tried every permutation I can of 'Z-Rotation' but nothing yet.

[image: My Nodes]

Thanks for your attention.

Update: Though it was enough, but no... not yet. I was misreading the screen. When I zoomed in, it wasn't correctly rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from *Float* to *Vector*, then you can just type in rotation as the attribute, from there you can control the XYZ rotations.

Comment: Hello and welcome, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer, low quality posts may be removed at some point. Could you edit your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works? Perhaps add a few screenshots illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) otherwise it may be converted into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Duarte. You got me pointed in the right direction. There was just a bit more data that needed to be conveyed to flesh it out. Here is the array:

[image: Corrected Node Array]

The keys here, for everyone else that will be inevitably confused by this particular example (rotation variation):

1. As @simsam noted, ensure that the Attribute is set to: Rotation
2. Ensure that the Min and Max for X & Y (Values 1 & 2) are set to Zero
3. Set the Min and Max for Z (Value 3) as the min and max (and thus constitute the degree of variation from the default orientation)

Extrapolating out from that, it looks like standard attribute labels are fine, I just need to remember to also set the appropriate *type* (in many cases, when dealing with traditional mesh attributes, *Vector* will be the choice).

Comment: The answer is actually from user @simsam, not mine, I just edited it for formatting. Don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).